# clear interval on hover Jquery

Tags: jquery, slideshow, carousel, jquery-hover, clearinterval

I would like to pause my slider on mouse hover and for that I need to clear the interval. The interval is controlled by my wordpress theme. website here http://blog.vishopper.com/

```
if($('#zSlider').length != 0){

$('#zSlider').carousel({interval: parseInt(zAlive_i18n.slider_pause_time) }).bind('slid',function(){

$('#zSlider .description li.active').removeClass('active');

$('#zSlider .description li:eq(' + $('#zSlider .carousel-inner .active').index('#zSlider .carousel-inner .item') + ')').addClass('active');

});
```

it used to pause on hover by default but that functionality has broken.

Comment: if feel like you should have this much code when working with jQuery. js

Comment: I'd have to think that the carousel would contain the interval id somewhere which you can use to clear...

Comment: I didn't code the thing, just trying to make it work like I want to.

Comment: so you want the carousel to pause on hover essentially?

Comment: yes, I want it to wait out the 1000 ms delay for .mouseover and then for it to pause on that slide.

Comment: here is the whole carousel http://pastebin.com/XbAvBjGT

Comment: I'm stumped, doing more googling. I can't find where the interval is kept either.

Comment: ok, I removed the parsint stuff because I don't know where slider pause time was being stored and put the interval right in there. I'm going to ask a new question now.